# Check for changes in a ASP.net form

Tags: .net, change-tracking

I want to check if there have been any changes to a form on my ASP.NET webpage, What are my options?

Should i check if the viewstate has changed or should create a flag in the code-behind, triggered by webcontrol events like TextChanged for Textboxes or SelectedIndexChanged for Dropdownlists?

Comment: I need to check if there are any changes when i submit the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the sent values in attributes. Something like:

```
Textbox1.Text = <Sent Text>
Textbox1.Attributes.Add "OldText",Textbox1.Text
```

On postback, you can compare:

```
If Textbox1.Text <> Textbox1.Attributes("OldText") Then
   ' Text is different
```

You would have to do that for every control in your form. Of course, you could write a procedure to do this in a more automatic way, like iterating through all your controls.

Comment: Maybee this is the best solution for me, i shall figure out how to implement this solution to dropdownlist also.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way: submit that form, and at server-side, compare sent values with those stored in your data layer.

Answer (score 0):

Set the proper `OnChange` event (different for some controls, i.e. Droplist:`OnSelectedIndexChanged`) for all controls to call a single `form_Changed` function. In that function, set a global variable to true. Then in the Button Click Handler, check that value.  All "Changed" events trigger before the button Click handler.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="loginallowed" Checked="true" OnCheckedChanged="form_Changed" />
<asp:TextBox ID="tbFirst" runat="server" CssClass="form-control required" OnTextChanged="form_Changed"/>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
private Boolean formChanged = false;
protected void form_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    formChanged=true;
}
protected void btn_Click()
{
    if(!formChanged) return;
}
```